# Linksys WRT54GS as a client

Tags: windows

I have a PC which I have connected to a public Access Point via a RALINK dongle.
Now I want to connect my Linksys Router on this PC which the router will consider as the gateway and provide internet to other stations in the house through the Linksys router.

How can this be done in Windows 7? I mean connect my router on an Ethernet port on the PC and allow other stations to go through it in the house?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide to share your internet connection:

**[Step by step Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) setup](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-vista/step-by-step-internet-connection-sharing-ics-setup-in-vista/)**

Then configure the Linksys router to obtain the WAN IP dynamically (DHCP) and connect its WAN port to the network controller of your Windows 7 machine.

Now other computer in your house can connect via network cable or wireless to the Linksys router and access the internet through your shared connection.